# Autofill Excel if A1 = sheet2 A1 then B1 = Sheet2 B2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am maintaining an excel sheet where Sheet1 A1 would be the name of people and B2 would be their contact number. All of the details are in sheet 2 row A and B.

So, what I want is if I put a valid name (i.e. should be in Sheet2 A) then it automatically finds the number of that name and adds in the second row. Is this possible? I have around 10-15 contacts there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Sheet `workers list` is as follows:

[image]

then in `Cell B2` of Sheet `assignment received` enter either of the following formulas

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'workers list'!A2:B10,2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=INDEX('workers list'!B2:B10,MATCH(A1,'workers list'!A2:A10,0))
```

[image]

Change range as required.

Comment: The second one works perfectly ( the first one didn't work). :D Just a little issue is I am not sure, but B2:B10 and A2:A10 automatically increases. Like if I paste this formula to A1 then formula works like I expect. but on when I paste this formula in A3 the "B2:B10" "A2:A10" changes to "B3:B11" and A3:A11". Any idea?

Comment: @AashirLV - Use `=INDEX('workers list'!$B$2:$B$10,MATCH(A1,'workers list'!$A$2:$A$10,0))`

Comment: Works perfectly. After 6 months I figured this out. :D Can't thank you enough for the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula in sheet -1 B2 cell "=IF(A2="","",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,0))"

and Dropdown this formula till you want

[Sheet-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stwyA.jpg)
[Sheet-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw1kl.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure where to place the formula. My sheet1 is named 'assignment received' and my sheet 2 is 'workers list'.